# Canon MX925 in KDE 4.14 ok- but unable to locate in CUPS/Plasma

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, cups, kde-plasma-5

I'm confused and I could need your help with installing a wireless Canon printer MX925 (on Plasma 5.6.3).
I still have a running KDE 4.14.10 system, Kernel 4.3.6 with a working Canon MX925 printer.
The 'cups-filters' are of old version net-print/cups-filters-1.0.71
On another laptop I have installed a fresh Sabayon (amd64 16.04) with Plasma 5.6.3, where I want to install the same printer using the same network.
CUPS is already installed by Anaconda. 
On here, 'cups-filters' are of version: net-print/cups-filters-1.8.3
So, then I installed the 'Gutenprint-5.2.10' package from repo.
Next step is to add a printer in CUPS, 'adding a printer', where the wireless MX925 is discovered by CUPS itself as connection:
dnssd://Canon%20MX920%20series._ipp._tc ... 0D6038F72A

Next step is to chose a printer driver from the list, where I select the same as on my KDE system:
Manufacturer Canon, driver Canon MX920 series - CUPS+Gutenprint v. 5.2.10(en)

So far, so good. Now, when I want to start printing a test page, on my Plasma laptop, I don't receive a print out, instead I get an error message:

MX925 - Idle - Unable to locate printer MX925-local'.

When I start: system-config-printer

I can create a debug file with many lines, with at least some interesting:

...

'D [06/May/2016:12:06:24 +0200] [Client 220] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=IPP_STATE_DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0',
               'D [06/May/2016:12:06:24 +0200] [Client 220] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=181',
               'D [06/May/2016:12:06:24 +0200] [Client 220] Flushing write buffer.',
               'D [06/May/2016:12:06:24 +0200] [Client 220] New state is HTTP_STATE_WAITING',
               'D [06/May/2016:12:06:24 +0200] [Client 220] Waiting for request.',
               'D [06/May/2016:12:06:24 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"',

I don't understand this. In between, I have tried to select different printer drivers from the Canon list:

1. MX920 series - Foomatic/gutenprint-ijs-5.2(en)
2. MX925 series - Foomatic/gutenprint-ijs-simplified5.2(en)
3. PIXMA MX925 - CUPS+Gutenprint 5.2.10(en)
4. PIXMA MX925 - Foomatic/gutenprint-ijs-5.2(en)
5. PIXMA MX925 - Foomatic/gutenprint-ijs-simplified5.2(en)

So, my question is: can I locate the correctly matching files on my old KDE system and copy it to my Plasma,
and also select those exact files in CUPS - printer installation Such like cloning? For this. I would need to know the exact location of all involved files on the origin.

In the list of printer drivers there are often driver names repeated. Are they the same or (how to find out?) different?
Any idea, what could I do?

Thank you for joining.

-Auguste

p.s. There is no problem for libreoffice to detect this printer as scanner. And scan works without installing Scangear from Canon website...

Answer (score 0):

**** Update ****

I have found a solution, inspired by this discussion:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=92011

For me the solution was to insert the printers ip address into the /etc/hosts file:

```
192.168.1.39     MX925.local
```

After this I had to restart some services:

`systemctl restart cups
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reload avahi-daemon`

so that my changes could take effect then.
Now, I am able to use my wireless MX925 - All-in-One as printer and (I could do already before) as scanner.
I hope, I could help users here with similar problems.

Thank you for your interest.

-Auguste